# Is it possible to get rid of that extra @Resource annotation for Websphere-managed DataSource?

Tags: java, ejb, websphere, openjpa

I have EJB application that is using OpenJPA persistence unit from WebSphere 8.5. The DataSource is configured on the WebSphere with the following settings:

- Scope: cells:pxxxxNodexxCell
- Name: MYAPP_001
- JNDI name: jdbc/MYAPP/DS001
- Component-managed authentication alias: MYAPP_001
- Mapping-configuration alias: (none)
- Container-managed authentication alias: (none)

The persistence unit is configured so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="myapp" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/MYAPP/DS001</jta-data-source>
        <class>...</class>
        <properties>
            ...
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Now I'm importing it into EJB:

```
@PersistenceContext(name = "myapp")
private EntityManager em;
```

The problem is, that with the following configuration the data source can not be resolved:

> Caused by: 
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: The persistence
>   provider is attempting to use properties in the persistence.xml file
>   to resolve the data source. A Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) driver
>   or data source class name must be specified in the
>   openjpa.ConnectionDriverName or javax.persistence.jdbc.driver
>   property. The following properties are available in the configuration:
>   "WsJpaJDBCConfigurationImpl@83f2eb8d: PDQ disabled: AccessIntent
>   Task=disable".    at
>   org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.newDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.createConnectionFactory(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:849)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getDBDictionaryInstance(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:602)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.endConfiguration(MappingRepository.java:1518)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:531)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:456)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.PluginValue.instantiate(PluginValue.java:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.conf.MetaDataRepositoryValue.instantiate(MetaDataRepositoryValue.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ObjectValue.instantiate(ObjectValue.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.newMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:967)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.getMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:958)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.makeReadOnly(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:644)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:203)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:227)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:72)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:35)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAEMPool.getEntityManager(JPAEMPool.java:167)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPATxEntityManager.getEMInvocationInfo(JPATxEntityManager.java:247)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPATxEntityManager.getEMInvocationInfo(JPATxEntityManager.java:179)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAEntityManager.createQuery(JPAEntityManager.java:299)

What I need, is to provide `DataSource` resource mapping in **any** of the EJB's using the `EntityManager`:

```
@Resource(name = "java:comp/env/jdbc/MYAPP/DS001", lookup = "jdbc/MYAPP/DS001", shareable = true, authenticationType = Resource.AuthenticationType.CONTAINER)
private DataSource ds;
```

This is very unelegant solution for me, because:

1. It's very confusing. It need to be declared only once, in **any** of the EJB's that are using `@PersistenceContext`. That `DataSource` may not be used at all in the Java code, and in my case it is not used. It will be hard to understand what that declaration is doing in that file, and why it is only in one file.
2. It's duplicating the configuration, that is provided in the other place. I need to specify the name of the resource once again (it was already specified in persistance.xml).
3. It's storing of the configuration in the source code. Quite a dirty anti-pattern.
4. Technically, it requires `javax.annotation.Resource` from Java 7, while my project is using Java 6. But the WebSphere runtime hat altered version of that annotation, so everything is working, but requires compiling with javac from WebSphere runtime, instead of standard JDK.

Is it possible to get rid of that annotation? What do I need to use as alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The java:comp/env/ format represents a resource reference, so somehow you must define it. You have a few options to not define a dummy data source:

1.Define a resource at the class level - this is fully supported in Java 6 - and it correctly defines a resource reference:

```
@Resource(name="jdbc/dsRef", type=javax.sql.DataSource.class, lookup="jdbc/DS")
public class MyBean implements MyBeanLocal {
```

One more clarification to this and your code - in name you actually should just give a reference name (without `java:comp/env`) and then in persistence.xml you put java:comp/env/refName.  Lookup defines the actual JNDI name registered on the server. You may skip defining a lookup and bind the reference to a resource during installation or via a binding file.

2.Use deployment descriptor

Create a deployment descriptor (web.xml or ejb-jar.xml) and define a resource reference for each EJB there. You will no longer have to place a DataSource with @Resource in your class.

3.Not use reference at all

Although I'd not recommend it, you can use an actual server JNDI datasource name in persistence.xml. Then you don't need a DataSource in an EJB as no reference is used.

```
<jta-data-source>jdbc/MYAPP/DS001</jta-data-source>
```

But in that case, you will not see in the admin console that the application is using a DataSource and you will not be able to change that mapping to a different data source jndi name if needed.

And in clarification of your comment:

> Technically, it requires javax.annotation.Resource from Java 7, while
>   my project is using Java 6. But the WebSphere runtime hat altered
>   version of that annotation, so everything is working, but requires
>   compiling with javac from WebSphere runtime, instead of standard JDK

[javax.annotation.Resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html) is a part of Java EE 6, which is implemented by WebSphere. You don't need Java v7, but a fully complaint Java EE 6 application server. You are creating a Java EE app not a Java SE one. That's why you need container classes to resolve that annotation. Its nothing 'altered' by WebSphere, just following the specification.

Comment: This is all great information.  As clarification, `@Resource(lookup=...)` was not added until Java SE 7, but it is required by EE 6, so application servers (including WAS) do override this annotation class.  This does cause complications for compilation, but as you suggested, you can use alternatives like lookup-name in the DD or a binding (bnd file or deployment).